# I got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id when try to use viewpager

Tags: android

I am using viewpager in my android project. In the fragment I need to open a pdf file. I used library to handle pdf file opening .without pdf opening methods(read() and open()) this is working fine. but when I call those two methods it gives me above exception

This is my main class

```
    package com.android.pageviewers;    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

    public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity implements Communicator{
    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
   View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page_view, container, false);
   List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();   
   pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);        
   ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)contentView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
  return contentView;
}


    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 1"));
        fList.add(MyFragment.newInstance("Fragment 2"));
        //fList.add(MyFragment3.newInstance("Fragment 3"));

        return fList;
    }

    private class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void viewPdf() {

        //ShowPdf.read();

    }
    }


This is my fragment

   package com.android.pageviewers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.epapyrus.plugpdf.SimpleDocumentReader;
import com.epapyrus.plugpdf.SimpleDocumentReaderListener;
import com.epapyrus.plugpdf.SimpleReaderFactory;
import com.epapyrus.plugpdf.core.viewer.DocumentState;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "EXTRA_MESSAGE";


    // create a listener for receiving provide pdf loading results
            SimpleDocumentReaderListener m_listener = new
 SimpleDocumentReaderListener() {

                @Override
                public void onLoadFinish(DocumentState.OPEN state) {
                }
            };


    public static final MyFragment newInstance(String message)
    {
        MyFragment f = new MyFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        f.setArguments(bdl);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String message = getArguments().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);
        TextView messageTextView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        messageTextView.setText(message);
        read();
        return v;
    }


    public void read(){

        String fileName = new String("1.pdf");      
        AssetManager am = getResources().getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream is = am.open(fileName);
            //SimpleDocumentReader.openFile();

            int size = is.available();
            if (size > 0) {
                byte[] data = new byte[size];
                is.read(data);
                open(data);
            }

            is.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public void open(byte[] words) {
        try {           

        // pdfviewer create.
        SimpleDocumentReader viewer =    
    SimpleReaderFactory.createSimpleViewer(getActivity(), m_listener); 
        // pdf data load.
        viewer.openData(words, words.length, "");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("KS", "error ", ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }


     }
```

when i run this project it gives me the mentioned error.I have already added the id for pageviewer.

```
10-01 08:56:45.273: E/AndroidRuntime(2824): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a003c (com.android.pageviewers:id/pager) for fragment MyFragment{41468878 #1 id=0x7f0a003c android:switcher:2131361852:1}
```

Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I removed onCreate method from my main class and the the onCreateView.Now there is no any exception.but it doesn't show me the pdf  file,just blan page,i am unable to swipe too.

Comment: Can you post the layout xml too?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited]

Try replacing your `onCreate()` method with the following `onCreateView()`. You need to inflate the layout yourself.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_page_view, container, false);
    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();   
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);        
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)contentView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    return contentView;
}
```

Comment: I tried with your solution,now there is no exception.But i am unable to view the pdf file on viewpager.I am getting just blank screen